# Problems solving this parametric equation

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, parametric

Working in the ring $$\mathbb Z_7[x]$$
with
$$p(x)=x^4+1$$
$$q(x)=x^2+3x-k$$
I should be able to find the parameter
$$k\in \mathbb Z_7[x]$$
that would satisfy the polynomial division
$$p(x):q(x)$$
I was just able to find the zeros of the `p(x)` function (of which only `x-1` is set in the ring) but I don't know if that is useful and how to proceed.
Surfing the web I just managed to find examples where the k is in the dividend but inverting that method doesn't seem to work. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

over the real numbers we have
$$   x^4 + 1 = (x^2 - x \sqrt 2 + 1)(x^2 + x \sqrt 2 + 1)  $$
In the field of seven elements, $2$ is a square, namely
$$ 3^2 \equiv 2 \pmod 7 \; , $$
$$  4^2 \equiv 2 \pmod 7 \; . $$